# How could I get acces to the hyperlink, using it's name or caption

Tags: qtp

in my test, i need to surf through site, using hyperlink, which name (and the caption) is 'next'. I added it from my application, and used a 'click' method. It is working only for the first time, so browser navigated to the second page and had stucked there. My code is below:

```
Do 
    Set msgList = Browser("Incoming — Gmail").Page("ВIncoming — Gmail").ChildObjects(msgDesc)
    msgCount = msgCount + msgList.Count()

    Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "MessagesCount", "Messages: " & msgCount

    'MsgBox msgList.Count() ' in a purpose of debugging

Loop While SurfNextPage(Browser("Incoming — Gmail").Page("Deliver successfull"))

'Function surfs to the next page, if it possible
' currPage -- current page
'Return: TRUE, if  link to the next page is available, otherwise ELSE
Function SurfNextPage(currPage)
Dim bResult

   Set hlDesc = Description.Create
   hlDesc("name").Value = "next"

   Set hlList = currPage.ChildObjects(hlDesc)
   For i = 0 to (hlList.Count()-1)
       Set urlNextMail  = hlList(i)     'there would be the only element in list

   Next

   bResult   = urlNextMail.Exist

   If bResult Then
       urlNextMail.Click 'surfs to the next page

   End If

   SurfNextPage = bResult

End Function
```

The web-page has a difficult structure -- a lot of DIV and Java, so i can't say exactly to which frame or table this link belongs, but there are no another links with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some  back and forth in the comments it appears that the `next` link *does* exist on the last page but clicking it does nothing.

You should modify the description you're using in order to identify the link so that it only matches links that move to the next page and not the link that is invisible (but there) on the last page.

---

**Original answer:**
Since you're always using the same page to call `SurfNextPage` then this method should work (assuming there is a `"next"` link in the object repository under said page).

If you want to use different pages then you should use descriptive programming, i.e. not use an object from the repository, instead use something like this `currPage.Link("text:=next")` this will look for a link with `"next"` as its text property.

Another thing that may be going wrong is that an object is identified before a navigation and then the navigation invalidates the object. If this is the case you should use the `RefreshObject` method (as explained in the documentation).

If none of these suggestions help please provide more information on what exactly is getting "stucked"

Comment: I detected my hyperlink, using ChildObjects(). But the loop never stops: Exist() always returns 'True'

Comment: @Eugene, if `Exist` is always true does the Click succeed?

Comment: Yes, click succeeds. And when browser reaches the last page, it can't detect, that link is unclickable. That cause the endless loop

Comment: So you're saying that in the last page `urlNextMail.Exist` still returns true? Have you tried highlighting the link from the object repository and seeing what element it thinks it's identifying? It sounds like the HTML element is really there (perhaps hidden) and you'll have to tweak the description so it only fits the visible links in the application (also perhaps smart identification is finding it by mistake, in which case you can disable smart id for this test object).

Comment: On the last page it highlights nothing. I've updated the code int the question

Comment: Try doing `MsgBox urlNextMail.GetROProperty("outerhtml")` to see if it finds an object (if it does you can then look for that object in the DOM).

Comment: it's an A tag:
<A class=b-pager__next href = "some_url">next</A>

Comment: So the link is found, compare to a next link that is active, it could be that the `className` is different or else you can check its `width` to see if it's visible.